# Lombok inheritance and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, lombok

Lombok: 1.16.18

Eclipse: Oxygen

I have an object with `@Getter` and `@Setter` as a base object:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of="uuid")
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable,Auditable {
```

`Auditable` requires setCreatedBy, which is included in BaseEntity.

However, the following object, which extends BaseEntity, receives an error of "The type Login must implement the inherited method Auditable.setCreatedBy(String)"

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Login extends BaseEntity{
```

Looking on the outline pane, `setCreatedBy` is properly generated on `BaseEntity`, but does not exist on `Login`. What am I configuring wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened, but a full rebuild eventually fixed it.  Not sure that was the issue though, as I had done several full builds since upgrading lombok.